# Геокодер (Яндекс Карт API)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Есть таблица с адресами (cvs), надо получить координаты через Геокодер, используя Яндекс JavaScript API, не через HTTP запросы.

Как можно записать получившиеся результаты в таблицу?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1. Приобрести расширенный коммерческий тариф для сохранения данных (на время действия лицензии);
2. написать JS-скрипт для импорта cvs и последовательного геокодирования адресов, а после экспорта обратно в таблицу.

Учитывая первый пункт целесообразней будет использовать не JS API а http-геокодер напрямую в любом удобном вам программном окружении, способном взаимодействовать с сетью.